# Understand the method to prevent an aysnc call from simultaneously called more than once in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

```
useEffect(() => {
  let didCancel = false;
  
  async function fetchJoke() {
    if (!didCancel) {
      let response = await fetch('https//api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
      let data = await response.json();
      setJoke(data);    
    }  
  }
  
  fetchJoke();
  
  //cleanup function
  //
  return () => {
    didCancel = true;
  };
}, [update]);
```

The cleanup function will be called later when the component unmounts or when the effect is re-run.

**Question**> I have difficulties to understand how the cleanup function can set the `didCancel = true`
which can determine whether or not `fetchJoke` will run the async operation.
Does `let didCancel = false` run each time when the component unmounts or when the effect is re-run?

Here we have two places where we modify the value of didCancel.

1> `let didCancel = false`

2> cleanup function

```
  return () => {
    didCancel = true;
  };
```

So which one wins in this case and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does let didCancel = false run each time when the component unmounts or when the effect is re-run?

That line of code runs every time the effect runs. So it will happen when the component mounts, plus when the dependency array changes. Additionally, in a dev build using [strict mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode), react will simulate the component mounting twice and thus it will run a second time on mount.

Note: every time the effect runs, this line is creating a *new* local variable. It is a separate variable from the last time the effect ran.

> Here we have two places where we modify the value of didCancel.
>
> 1> let didCancel = false
>
> 2> cleanup function
>
> ```
>  return () => {
>    didCancel = true;
>  };
> ```
>
> So which one wins in this case and why?

If the effect runs twice, then there are two `didCancel` variables, each in their own closure. The one from the first time the effect ran has had its cleanup function called, and thus is set to `true`. The one from the second time the effect ran is still set to `false`.

If code from the first effect runs (eg, because the fetch completes), it will only interact with the copy of the variable which is set to `true`. If code from the second effect runs, it will interact with the variable which is set to `false`.

Comment: Originally, I thought the logic behind this cleanup function is to prevent calling fetch('..') twice. However, based on my observation, this is not the case. The fetch('..') is called every single time when `update` is modified. if (!didCancel) { // the value of didCancel is always false.

Comment: Typically, the `if(!didCancel)` check is put *after* the fetch, before setting state or doing other stuff with the result of the fetch